# Error: invalid password(Not CSK password) in Building mobile app for blackberry using phonegap

Tags: java, ant, blackberry, cordova

I am new for building mobile app using phonegap, So I need desperate help from any one.

I have followed the steps whatever mentioned here, 
[I refered](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html)

Deploy to Simulator, Its Builded Successfully.

```
    \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test>ant blackberry load-simulator
Buildfile: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build.
xml

blackberry:

load-simulator:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: test.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 26 files to \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\
test\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build\test.zip

build:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks applicatio
n
     [exec] [INFO]                      Generating output files
     [exec] [INFO]                      BlackBerry WebWorks application packagin
g complete

load-simulator:
     [echo] Simulator directory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackB
erry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\simpack\7.0.0.318
     [echo] Simulator directory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackB
erry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\simpack\7.0.0.318
     [echo] Simulator executable=C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\Black
Berry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\simpack\7.0.0.318/9930.bat
     [echo] Closing all running simulators...
     [exec] No sessions currently running.
     [exec] Result: 1
     [echo] MDS directory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry W
ebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\mds
     [copy] Copying 4 files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBe
rry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\simpack\7.0.0.318

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 24 seconds
```

And I have tried to deploy to mobile device, the phonegap is not building the app successfully.

BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5

Ant : Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013

About java :

java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Blackberry Desktop Manager : 7.1.0

```
\xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test>ant blackberry load-device
Buildfile: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build.
xml

blackberry:

load-device:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: test.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\
test\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 26 files to \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\
test\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: \xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build\test.zip

load-device:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks applicatio
n
     [exec] [INFO]                      Starting signing tool
     [exec] [INFO]                      Signing complete
     [exec] [INFO]                      Generating output files
     [exec] [INFO]                      BlackBerry WebWorks application packagin
g complete
     [exec] RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
     [exec] Copyright 2001-2009 Research In Motion Limited
     [exec] Connecting to device...debug: COM error during Open: (0x80040008)
     [exec] Error: invalid password

BUILD FAILED
\xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\build.xml:45: The
 following error occurred while executing this line:
\xampp\htdocs\projects\mobilesapps\blackberry\test\blackberry.xml:53
: exec returned: 29

Total time: 30 seconds
```

Any one please guide me. I need to complete this today for one of my client. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the device password in your project config is wrong.
To deploy to a device you must configure the password in the `project.properties` file.

Yo should have:

```
qnx.device.password=1234
```

Where "1234" is your device password.

This usually happens when you are deploying to a device and then change to another device and forget to change the password.

Other things to check when you change device are:

- `qnx.device.ip`
- `qnx.device.pin` (only when you use debug tokens).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. But I am not able to find anything like above, for your reference i have shared my project.properties file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B14yJZmKjobVS2xSdFpyLTJDYVE/edit?usp=sharing) please check it and guide me.. thanks

Comment: Ok, so you are compiling for BB7. Then forget about my answer because what I said is for BB10. You have a problem at the very end, when deploying to the device. But the cods were compiled and signed according to the logs. You don't need the device password for javaloader. Pick the `.cod` files from the bin folder, and try to manually deploy them using javaloader from command line, or even easier, using desktop manager.

Comment: Thanks Smith, I have tried to deploy using javaloader from command line.. Its working fine for me. And how can I make its as installable one for the use of others or BB App World? Can you please guide me...

Comment: Ok, at least you were able to deploy it. Im sorry I couldn't help you to fix the ant install. About the binaries for app world, you just need the signed cods, that's all. I think you can upload them in a zip file, but can't remember.

Comment: Thanks, I did sign in process and the step to release version for BB App World, But When I copied .cod files to BB Device and trying to install it. But its not supporting.. give 907 invalid cod error/etc... Can anyone help this..